# Can I use a tallis gadol on 4 sticks as a hupa canopy

Tags: halacha, minhag, wedding, tallit-gadol

Can I use a tallis gadol on 4 sticks as a hupa canopy? Possible problems:

1. The minhag is not to use a tallis
2. It is disrespectful to the tallis

Comment: There is a nice article in Ohr Yisrael which discusses talis chuppah which has many minhagim and many ppl did use a talis with tzitizs,one such remez from the Torah is the mitzvah of tzitz is connected to ki yikach ish ,see parshas ki tezitzei perek 22 12,and 13

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33974/the-reason-for-a-tallit-being-used-as-a-chuppah

Comment: As I have seen this method used in a number of places, a few within the past 15 years, I didn't even know that there is a any problem doing this. Can you link some sources within your question? You are stating a firm assumption in the tone of a common "fact".

Comment: @DanF I have never seen it (the closest thing I saw was a photo of how under the chupa they go under a tales together) this is why I am asking

Comment: Fair point. However, not a question of distrust; just a question of strengthening the credibility of your statement. Apparently, some (Orthodox, if that matters) rabbi is allowing this to happen, as he is officiating. So, either he is uninformed (it's happened), or it is permissible. I agree that it is uncommon, at least from what I've seen. Then, again, of the few weddings I attend, most chuppot are "overly" fancy, so my stats are highly skewed.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I've attended Orthodox weddings where this was done. These have ranged the gamut of Hashkafah.

Comment: I was one such chupa holder for an orthodox wedding.  The tallis was the one being given by the bride to the groom.  We used ordinary round wooden sticks (actually push broom handles with the broom removed).  There was no issue.

Comment: I believe Yekkes do this.

Comment: As a post script, at the wedding reception, those of us who held up the chupa were given gifts...the broom part of the push brooms. :-)

Comment: @DoubleAA, yekkes wear wear the tallit over the couple, see Oppenheim's painting of a Jewish wedding.

Comment: why do you think it would be disrespectful to the tallis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Minhag of my family going back more than 100 years is indeed to use a Tallit. I don't know the source, but we come back from Shklov in Lita.

Answer (score 2):

i asked Rav Avraham Osdoba he told me he does not see why not,

so yes it is permitted